# Problem handling orientation change in custom view

Tags: android, view, orientation

I wrote a custom view that extends LinearLayout. It holds two views, a "header" and a "body". The custom view maintains "expanded" state that toggles on and off whenever the header view is clicked. When expanded, the body is VISIBLE and when not expanded, the body is GONE. I want to preserve the expanded state of this view when the device orientation changes, so I wrote onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState to save an expanded flag.

One problem is that if I reorient the device when any of these views is expanded, then the entire activity is redrawn without changing the orientation of the views. (If I change from portait to landscape, the screen stays in portrait.) If none of the custom views are expanded, the activity's view tree is reoriented correctly.

Here's my logic for the view's onRestoreInstanceState:

```
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
    SavedState ss = (SavedState) state;
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(ss.getSuperState());
    if (ss.expanded != mHeader.isExpanded()) {
        mHeader.toggleExpanded();
    }
    mBody.setVisibility(ss.expanded ? VISIBLE : GONE);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?